# Printing the k smallest values by order from small to largest in minimal heap in O(klog k)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, heap

I have a min heap `H` with `n` elements. The function `min(H,k)` prints the `k` smallest values by order from small to largest. In the end of the method, `H` still contains the `n` values. I was asked to give an algorithm of `min(H,k)` in `O(klogk)` and `O(k)` extra space. In the solutions they did as follows:

We will use an extra min heap `T` without any data. It will contain copies of elements of the original min heap `H` (There will be a two-way pointer between the values from `H` and `T`). The algo:

- Print the minimal element of `H` in `O(1)`.
- Insert into `T` the two children of the root of `H`.
- As long as we didn't print k values do:

  - Print the minimal element of `T` (lets call it `x`).
  - Remove `x` from `T`.
  - Insert into heap `T` the two children of `x` of heap `H` (if exists).

I don't understand why this algorithm is valid and what is worst, I don't understand the algorithm at all. I understand that we create a new heap `T`. I also understand why printing the minimal element of `H` is `O(1)`. I don't understand the "Insert into `T` the two children of the root of `H`" part. Does it inserts pointers of those children into heap `T` or just their values? If the answer is the second option, then how I know to follow to the next ones?

Answer (score 0):

The elements of `T` have to let you get at the elements and positions of the elements in the original heap.  If you can do that then you can find the next elements and you can find the values.

A variety of representations will work.  For example with the min heap array representation all that you need to know are the offsets into the array, with global constants for the length of the array and the start of the array.

The key insight as to why this works is that all operations on `T` are heap operations on a heap of size `O(k)`.  Therefore they each take `O(log(k))`.  There are `O(k)` operations needed so the result is `O(k log(k))`.